# $.getJSON not working in jQuery 1.10.2?

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I’m trying to load some JSON with jQuery and I'm getting mixed results depending on what version of jQuery I am using.

This first page (http://iaviglobal.com/json-3.html) uses jQuery 1.8.3 and it works just fine! All of the content on that page is pulled from a .json file on my server.

My second page (http://iaviglobal.com/json-4.html), however, uses jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery Migrate 1.2.1. My JSON call doesn’t work here! Here is my code:

```
  $.getJSON('/json/products.json', function(data) {
  alert ("json loaded");
        var output="";
        for (var i in data.products) {
            output+="<div class='product-line-item wrapper'><div class='product-image'><img src='/img/" + data.products[i].fileName + ".png alt='' width='150' height='100'></div><div class='product-model'>" + data.products[i].modelNumber + "</div><div class='product-specs'><ul><li>" + data.products[i].brightness + " Lumens</li><li>" + data.products[i].resolution + " Resolution</li><li>" + data.products[i].contrast + " Contrast Ratio</li></ul></div><a class='get-a-quote trigger-quote-modal'>Get a Quote</a><a class='download-pdf' href='/download/" + data.products[i].fileName + ".pdf'>Download PDF</a></div>";
        }

        output+="";
        document.getElementById("product-line-container").innerHTML=output;
  });
```

Can anyone explain to me what changed? I assume something became deprecated since 1.8.3 but I can't figure out what.

I created a third page here: http://iavi.com/glored/json-5.html. This page is stripped down and only includes a script to notify me if jQuery was successfully loaded or not and then the JSON code verbatim from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ combined with jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery Migrate 1.2.1.

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Still doesn’t work!

The only thing the console says “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method ‘getJSON’ of undefined”

Comment: The first page works fine for me, in the second page `$` is undefined, but `jQuery` is available, so you could wrap your code in `jQuery(function($) {...`

Comment: *"The only thing the console says “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method ‘getJSON’ of undefined”"* Re-read that error. It explains completely why your ajax request isn't working. `getJSON` doesn't exist on `undefined`. that means `$` is `undefined` and `undefined` expectedly doesn't have a `getJSON` method. You either didn't include jquery, or you've put it in no conflict mode.

Comment: @KevinB Well the thing is that jQuery IS loaded (the alert that pops up on page load confirms that, right?). And you're also suggesting that maybe the problem is that I've put jQuery in no conflict mode. But the other two responses here are suggesting that I DO put it in no conflict mode to fix it. So which is it? And like my post said, I'm loading the exact same code on two different page. And only the page loading jQuery 1.10.2 doesn't work. 1.8.2 works fine!

Comment: i'm just pointing out the facts. And, the answer's/comments aren't telling you to put it into no conflict mode, they're telling you to write the code as if it already is in no conflict mode (which, by looking at the error message, suggest that it is in fact in no-conflict mode.) If they were telling you to put it in no-conflict mode they would be telling you to use `$.noConflict()` (which isn't needed, don't jump to any conclusions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it could be a syntax error, try using jQuery in no-conflict mode:
`jQuery(document).ready(function ( $ )`